# Does Docker Swarm inter-service communication go through the routing mesh?

Tags: docker, routes, docker-swarm, docker-network

If I have a Docker Swarm with multiple nodes, connected to a user defined overlay network, and a service A tries to communicate with a service B, where service B has multiple replicas, which replica will get the message? I realize the routing mesh is an ingress thing, but something similar needs to happen in this case as well, right?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, there are 2 endpoint modes:

- `dnsrr` => service DNS resolve container IPs
- `default` => service DNS resolve Swarm ingress router

Swarm router is a pure ***** , it have lof of network problems (timeout, no route to host, zombies).

`dnsrr` will give all container IPs, it's cool but this can cause trouble with DNS cache (logstash, Php AMQP client...):

*"service A have DNS cache of X secondes, it can communicate with container B.1. Container B.1 crash, re-spawn with different IP ==> service A still sending to former IP"*

Also be careful in case of a container with multiple networks.

Answer (score 1):

By default, docker configures each service with a Virtual IP (VIP) that is implemented using [ipvs](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/software/ipvs.html) in the kernel. This performs round robin load balancing between each replica of the service for each distinct network connection (persistent network connections will remain connected to the same replica for the life of that TCP connection).

When the IP address being forwarded to is on another node, it uses overlay networking, implemented by vxlan in the kernel, to send those packets to the other nodes. If anything on the network is blocking the overlay networking ports, you'll see issues getting this to work. Docker has the [prerequisite ports](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/#create-an-overlay-network) in their documentation:

> - TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
> - TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
> - UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic

I often debug connectivity issues using tcpdump on each node to see if packets sent from one node are received at the destination. And if necessary, the overlay port can be changed with the `docker swarm init --data-path-port` flag when initializing the swarm cluster.

I prefer using the default overlay networking in most scenarios since it eliminates a class of DNS caching issues. If you use DNS round robin, each container in the swarm cluster may cache DNS results for replicas of your service and talk to old IP addresses used by that service for as long as the DNS cached result persists in that container's application. This can result in significant downtime during a rolling update while you wait for the application to refresh it's DNS results for a selected container. While I encountered issues with ipvs in the past, I haven't encountered those in recent versions of docker with a newer kernel, and the same kernel module is used by many kubernetes networking providers now, resulting in a lot more testing and stability.

If you want to get the individual IP addresses for replicas of a service, or use DNS RR, you can do this on a one off basis without disabling the service VIP. Instead, if you were to query `web` for the VIP of the web service, you could query `tasks.web` for the DNS RR of all replicas of that service (replacing `web` with your service name). I've only done this when I have applications that need to run a command against each replica, and I can see how it may be useful for sticky sessions.

As for how this relates to ingress networking and the service mesh, ingress networking is configured to route a specific port to that VIP on the ingress network on each node in the cluster. You'll see a VIP per overlay network that the service is connected to, including the ingress network if you have published ports, when you run a `docker network inspect -v ...` on your network.

The only times I consider disabling ingress networking is if I have a global service, a single node cluster, or a service running on a predictable list of nodes, and I want to avoid the extra network hop added by the service mesh. In those scenarios, I publish the port in "host" mode (see the [long syntax](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#long-syntax-1) for publishing ports). This will prevent you from running more than one replica on a node, but in most of my use cases, this is for a stateful app where multiple replicas doesn't make sense.